# How to disable gradle 'offline mode' in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to android studio IDE development. Every time when I imported a sample project that developed in the android studio, I am getting this error..

> No cached version of **com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0** available
>   for offline mode. Disable Gradle **'offline mode'** and sync project.

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: You may have not downloaded gradle entirely.

Comment: How can I check whether gradle downloaded or not. @Apurva.

Comment: Stay connected to internet while you open project in android studio. It will automatically download all required components

Comment: This problem happened only while importing the project. @Apurva

Comment: If you are using Android Studio 3.6 then refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60483387/5582162

Comment: I was looking for a way to disable "offline mode". Found many answers recommending to toggle it from preferences, but there were no "offline mode" checkbox there. The solution was to click on gradle toolbar on the right side of android studio and click on the pipe (toggle offline mode) button.

Comment: In Android Studio 3.6.3, Go to View-> Tool Windows-> Gradle
and from that click on "Toggle Offline Mode" Button
then Rebuild the Project

Comment: New location to toggle Gradle's offline mode
To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel..

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#3.6-gradle-offline-ui

Answer (score 266):

**New location in Android Studio 3.6+**

View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar.

Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel.

---

Old answer

**On Windows**:-

Go to **File -> Settings**.

And open the `'Build,Execution,Deployment'`.  Then open the

**Build Tools -> Gradle**

Then **uncheck**   -> **Offline work** on the right.

Click the **OK** button.

Then **Rebuild** the Project.

**On Mac OS**:-

go to **Android Studio -> Preferences**, and the rest is the same.
OR follow steps given in the image

[[image: For Mac go 1]

[image]

Comment: thanks mate you really solved my issue thanks a lot again :)

Comment: Is there any IDE performance gains when running Android Studio in offline mode?

Comment: @W.M., Yes, Check the security holes frequently reported in Android Studio group which can only be used if you are working online.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct for Android Studio 3.6+. The location of "Offline mode" has been changed. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features?utm_source=android-studio-4-0&utm_medium=studio-assistant-preview#gradle-offline-ui)

Comment: With Android Studio 3.6.1 I miss this toggle

Comment: Hey @hannesach, after reading https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151280278 I have discovered the solution reading the release notes https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#3.6-gradle-offline-ui

Comment: New location in Android Srudio 3.6+
**View > Tool Windows > Gradle** from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel.
[link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#3.6-gradle-offline-ui)

Comment: @AbdelalimHassouna thanks! Even Google's documentation doesn't show the correct instructions ! https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#low_memory it still shows to look in `Build, Execution, Deployment`

Comment: In Android Studio 3.6 (or above) Click on the Gradle Button Which is at right side, it will open up small window, here click on the “Toggle Offline Mode” icon for enable or disable toggle.

Comment: Right click "Reload Gradle Project" maybe needed after toggle offline mode

Comment: There is no such option as **Offline Mode** in Android Studio.

Comment: For newer version android studio Arctic fox 2021.3.1 or newer click on gradle at the right side of your screen and there will be toggle button for offline mode.

Comment: Please look here for Android studio 4.0+ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635762/what-is-disable-offline-mode-and-disable-gradle-offline-mode-and-this-settin

Comment: In case anyone is still wondering where to find it here is the linkfor reference. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#3.6-gradle-offline-ui

Answer (score 24):

Edit. As noted in the comments, this is no longer working with the latest Android Studio releases.

The latest Android studio seems to only reference to "Offline mode" via the keymap, but toggling this does not seem to change anything anymore.

---

In Android Studio open the settings and search for **offline** it will find the `Gradle` category which contains **Offline work**. You can disable it there.

[image: Gradle Offline work]

Comment: Is this the same as specifying `mavenLocal()` in **build.gradle**?

Comment: No `mavenLocal()` will result in gradle trying to find files in your local repo, if it can't find the library there it will fallback to `mavenCentral()`. The above will completely stop gradle from doing network calls to search for libs. If it hasn't the lib in the cache it will fail

Comment: @JqueryNinja I just checked. The offline work is still at the same place even with Android Studio 2.1.x

Comment: @mikepenz True true, that in addition, so I guess doing what I suggested also helps cause I was able to load images and maps. On demad slows down loading app onto phone and drawing maps/loading images

Comment: this is now no longer an accurate answer

Answer (score 23):

Gradle is in offline mode, which means that it won't go to the network to resolve dependencies.

Go to Preferences > Gradle and uncheck "Offline work".

Comment: There is no preferences toolbar in my android studio, what to do? Maybe i am not able to find it . Please help

Comment: n.b. There is no Preferences menu.  You need to go to File > Settings as explained in the other answers.

Comment: are you kidding with me you must tell accurate path because no one knows where is preferences see below answer >_<

Comment: Late comment: This answer is for Eclipse / Spring Tools Suite IDE not android studio, and the path is Window>Preferences>Gradle. Then check or uncheck the "Offline Mode" checkbox.

Comment: Go to the upper right corner. You will find it there.

Answer (score 18):

@mikepenz has the right one.

You could just hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (if you're using OSX and 1.4 android studio) and enter `OFFLINE` in the search box.

Then you'll see what mike have shown you.

Just deselect `offline`.

Comment: this still works

Answer (score 4):

Offline mode could be set in Android Studio and in your project.
To verify that gradle won't build your project in offline mode:

1. Disable gradle offline mode in Android Studio gradle settings.
2. Verify that your project's gradle.settings won't contain: startParameter.offline=true

Comment: The file becomes `settings.gradle`