# Does changing the build tools version make gradle build the project much slower?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

Recently I changed my build tools version to accomodate a new functionality, but my gradle build is painfully slow. I can sync the project and it will build in about 5 minutes, but after that another build starts that has has gone 30 minutes plus.
I went from build tools version '19.1.0' to '23.0.1'.

Current build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.macuser.itestify"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.13.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.2'
}
```

Previous build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.macuser.itestify"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
}
```

What could be causing it to build really slowly? and how do I fix it?
NB I'm running Android Studio 1.4

**EDIT:** After waiting for forever, I get this error

```
9:45:07 AM Sending jdwp tracking request failed!
9:45:07 AM Adb connection Error:EOF
9:45:07 AM Connection attempts: 1
```

Comment: it might be downloading that version of build tools

Comment: I already have it though! Thats why its so odd.

Comment: why should you not ruining it on offline mode so its to taking too much time to build. this link might be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio

Comment: I've tried to put it in offline mode, I've tried to even add the gradle.properties file with the parallel processing variables to true..no luck

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it slower the gradle built speed.I have also tried building the app by changing the versions.It has no effect on the time.

Comment: But the thing is, when I return it to its previous build.gradle configurations, it builds just fine..

Comment: I was having the same problem.When i built the project with the newer version 24.0.0 it throws me an error but it works fine for me on version 23.0.3.

Comment: they all took forever to build

Comment: What are the specifications of your pc?

Comment: MAC OSX 10.6.8, 4gb RAM, 2.16GHz Intel Dual Core.. enough info?

Comment: Yes,Try reinstalling the android studio.

Comment: I'll pass on that one, I did this a while ago and it brought more problems than solutions. Thanks though.