# could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'

Tags: web, gradle, mybatis

I am studing Mybatis and this is my build.gradle file
[image]

but when I refresh it,IntelliJ IDEA told me "could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'"
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of code, but include the code in a code-block

Comment: Thanks,Sorry about that,I'll be care next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you have an "offline mode" turned on, while created your Gradle project in IDE. Check the project setting, find a Gradle tab and turn off "Offline mode". [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio) you can find some more related info, about the way to disable it.

Note, that this option is used to turn off any Gradle network activity and make it impossible to download your dependencies if the are not yet cached or not added via file dependencies.

Comment: Thanks!! I've successfully downloaded all the dependencies I need.