# Error:(33, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.bumbtech.glide:glide:3.7.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-glide

I am trying to use the features from Github to create load images in my android  but when I tried to sync the project I got this error

***Error:(33, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.bumbtech.glide:glide:3.7.0***

These are the Grade Scripts (Module app) Dependancies that im using

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumbtech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
As mentioned in the comment. The dependency was not correct.

replace:
**com.github.bumbtech.glide**
with
**com.github.bumptech.glide**

---

Checking on the **Maven Repository** also shows that it is available: 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.bumptech.glide/glide/3.7.0

Please make sure your Android Studio configurations do not define the **offline mode** which would prevent new dependencies from being downloaded. 
You can find some more information regarding the **gradle offline mode** here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31235328/325479

Comment: The dependency wasan't correct i have written "bumb" insteasd of "bump" that was the only problem. Now its working fine

Comment: Yeah. Edited my answer to show this, just in case someone is searching for it