# Gradle is not Syncing

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded the Open-event-Android project of Fossasia from Github and imported it to Android Studio but I get this error "Error in Android Studio Plugin cannot be resolved from https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle because Gradle is running is offline mode "
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC3Jt.png)

I don't know what is meant by "Gradle is running in offline mode". If it is saying that I am not connected to the internet, well I am using a proxy net and I have set the HTTP proxy to automatically detect.
I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: hi could you please accept one reply if they helped you?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to deabilitate the offline mode?
there is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio) that explains what to do. This could be a great way to start: checking if is enabled the offline mode.Or at least is what sound more reasonable to do as the error message say to you that cannot resolve from the link mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when there's a plugin or some 3rd party library that's not available locally and it needs to connect to the internet for downloading and installing the same.