# My Application is not Refreshing

Tags: android

I am testing my application on a Samsung tablet where it launches fine, but when I make changes to the application on Android Studio, the changes do not reflect on the tablet. The tablet continues to display the first version of the application.

Comment: are you using InstantRun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**check this list**

1. Do you use InstantRun?(disable [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/4797289))
2. Do you use the gradle offline?(disable [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794890/4797289))

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue might be with Instant Run. Try disabling it and run again.