# I think I had messed up things with my gradle..The app is only running on nougat even on targeting marshmallow or lower...

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

If I am lowering more it is showing error...Even on lowering compile sdk it is saying that some dependencies will only work with nougat

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android
{
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.admin.clicknorder"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
compile 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
//compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If any more information will require..i will edit my question

Comment: Your targetSdkVersion  and compileSdkVersion  is totally different

Answer (score 0):

You are only targeting 3 devices from 21 to 23. that is really a bad idea. Replace your gradle by below. You need to install 27 version (latest) if not available.

Turn off gradle offline mode if not. [how to turn off gradle offline mode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android
        {
            compileSdkVersion 27
            buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.example.admin.clicknorder"
                minSdkVersion 15
                targetSdkVersion 27
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
            productFlavors {
            }
        }

def SUPPORT_LIB_VER = '27.0.2'
def FIREBASE_VER = '11.8.0'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER"
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    compile 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
//compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$FIREBASE_VER"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$FIREBASE_VER"
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```