# Android Studio Bug Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Hello Everyone I've got a problem with starting a new project with android studio and it's about Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3 and I have searched for the package but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your version of android studio in gradle classpath! Or you can find the latest version of gradle in the **gradle site** and put it in the gradle.build file in the gradle scripts!
Make sure that your gradile isn't offline checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio) .

If your country blocked from Google connect the vpn and try.