# gradle sync failed while importing a project

Tags: android, gradle

I was trying to import a project from GitHub to Android Studio and this is the error log I keep getting:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not download manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:25.1.0): No cached version available for offline mode
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1s 822ms)
```

Can someone please help with a way out?

Comment: And what does the "IDE log" that you should consult state? Did you try deactivating the gradle offline mode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You're in offline mode, uncheck it by Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Offline Work and then re-sync grade

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the offline mode in your Android studio settings. Go to preferences --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Gradle and now uncheck the "Offline work" checkbox. You can alternatively do a search as well in your preferences window. Just type "offline", here is the screenshot[image]