# GitHub project import in android studio causing trouble

Tags: java, android, jar

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@productDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@productDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@productDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@productReleaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@productReleaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@productAlphaUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@productAlphaUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@productBetaUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@productBetaUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@ciDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@ciDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@ciDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@ciReleaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@ciReleaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@ciAlphaUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@ciAlphaUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@ciBetaUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@ciBetaUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@developDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@developDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@developDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@developReleaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@developReleaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@developAlphaUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@developAlphaUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':Calendula@developBetaUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9)
Open File
Show Details

I am new in the android studio so please help me to import this project in Android SDK.

Comment: add build.gradle file

Comment: can you explain me in detail?

Comment: post here the content inside the app level build.gradle file so we can help

Comment: Check weather your offline mode option is disabled. https://stackoverflow.com/q/28712025/6891563

Comment: @Khemraj offline mode is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check weather your offline mode option is disabled. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28712025/6891563).

If enabled, please disable it and Build project again.

Comment: after disable and rebuild the project it will give an error warning: the '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-Xbuild-file' is specified

Comment: I get lot of warnings in my apps, just ignore all warnings.

Comment: Try running app in device, if it is successful then your problem is solved.

Comment: ok ignore it but it can't run, error running app because of no task to execute is specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6gmmQZsuLE)

1. Copy your repo url
2. Choose "Checkout project from Version Control" in android studio welcome screen
3. Choose Git
4. Paste your repo url, define your project folder
5. Click Test to test your connection (optional)
6. Click Clone