# Android Studio - Could not download sdk-common.jar

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn Android programming. I installed Android Studio and installed the SDK for 28 - 24. Then I started a new project and set the minimum level to 26. As soon as Android Studio creates the project it attempts to build the project and immediately presents this error:

```
Error:Could not download sdk-common.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.4):
    No cached version available for offline mode
```

I've tried searching but haven't found any solution.
How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Error:Could not download sdk-common.jar
>   (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.4): No cached version available for
>   offline mode

- You should **`Uncheck offline`** work at first.

**`File -> Settings ->Build, Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle ->`** 
Uncheck Offline work

Then ***Clean-Rebuild*** and **`GRADLE`** your project.

Comment: it isn't. you most likely accidentally enabled it

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable offline mode in android studio so that it can download all the required components /dependencies from network that are not available offline.

See this for how to disable offline mode in android studio: [How to disable gradle 'offline mode' in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio)