# Android Studio 3.2 showing unknown host error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After installing Android studio and creating a new project, I get the following message:
[image]

and in the "Build: Sync" section I get the following error:

[image]

After clicking in "Try Again" nothing changes. How can I fix it?

Comment: please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794890/4748607) for setting gradle offline and sync.

Comment: please check Offline Mode is **ON** or **OFF** in Gradle Setting. if is **Off** then please turn **ON**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check your proxy. make sure you have access to jcenter URL. It happens to me when trying to make a new project or add dependencies in my office because of proxy restriction. To check proxy, open:

> File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Setting > HTTP Proxy

You can use auto-detect proxy or manual proxy if you have proxy on your network. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the google() repo in the top level gradle file, also it should be before jcenter():

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
          google()
          jcenter()
      }


dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
   }
}

allprojects {
     repositories {
              google()
             jcenter()
  }
}
```

Check gradle is on offline or online mode:

```
File -> Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle->uncheck Offline work->Click the OK button->Rebuild the Project
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. The Offline box for the Gradle is uncheck and in the section build.gradle it seems that the google() repo is before jcenter(). Here's a link to it (https://i.imgur.com/vR50GjW.png).

Comment: Also, here's what I see on build.gradle: `buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
`