# How can we disable offline mode in Android Studio?

Tags: android, offline

How can we disable the offline mode of Android Studio from its UI?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable gradle 'offline mode' in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 14):

You can simply click on the gradle tab from the right and choose the icon shown by the arrow. Forgive me for using black for the arrow color, I am very new to macs.

[image: Gradle offline mode]

Comment: God i tried everything to disable 'offline mode' on a mac. This is the only working solution

Comment: This icon is really very confusing. I hope they add a more intuitive option to change this.

Comment: Even if i uncheck or check, android studio is requesting the offline mode to be disabled

Comment: @ekibet in that case you probably have an error in your build.gradle file. Check and fix it and everything should work as intended

Answer (score 0):

[image: uncheck offline Work]

Go to the File > Setting > Gradle and then Uncheck Offline Work and then you can sync project (Make sure internet is connected)

Answer (score 0):

In **MAC OSX**, **Android Studio** - **Preferences** - **Build, Execution and Deployment** - **Gradle** - **Offline work** - **uncheck** it and **apply/ok**

Answer (score -1):

Please 
do as follow

**File> Settings> Build,Executaion,Deployment> Gradle**

On above path there will be checkbox showing offline work. Uncheck it and Apply it.