# Problem with sync of gradle in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I was developing a Space Shooter Game, and until yesterday wverything was perfectly, but today, when I try to run my app, I get the followin error

```
Execution failed for task ':android:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':android:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.0-6503028.
     Required by:
         project :android
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.0-6503028 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.0-6503028 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.0-6503028 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.0-6503028 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.0-6503028 available for offline mode.

Possible solution:
 - Disable offline mode and rerun the build
```

So as sugest Android Studio, I Disable the offline mode, and then run, getting the following error:

```
``
Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.1.0-6503028/aapt2-4.1.0-6503028.pom'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

And guess what?, when I disable the Gradle offline mode, I return to the firts error again, so I quite lose on this.

If you know some way to solve, I bless you.

Thanks for advance!

Comment: have u sync-ed project?

Comment: Yes, and always return to the previous error

Comment: have u followed these instuctions?)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio

Comment: Of course, but I don't know why I haven't these button on my Android Studio Interface... Instance of doing like this I just disable from gradle window to right.

Comment: do you use proxy in your gradle properties file?

Comment: No, I don't use proxy in my gradle properties files. Should I do?

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, please share it.

Comment: Did you find the solution? if yes, please share it.

Comment: The solution waas the acepted answer by Aaliya Saiyed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select clean project from build menu and try to run your project