# What or where is "Disable Gradle offline mode" in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-4.1

I am using Android Studio version 4.1, and behind a proxy. I have already setup Proxy settings and the SDK download works fine.

But when I create a new Project, it's throwing error, like:

```
Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required

Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

Where the last line of above (the "Disable...") is blue,
like a URL, hence I simply clicked the URL,
but then the same error keeps coming.

On searching for "offline" in the settings, I find below snapshot:

[image: Gradle Offline settings not there in the Android Studio Settings]

I remember finding Gradle's "offline" mode easily using search in settings (in older Android Studio versions);

Where can these be found in the latest Android Studio???

Answer (score 79):

If you want to disable/enable Gradle offline mode:

- **Click** on the **Gradle tab** (from the right side of your Android Studio)
- **Select/Unselect** the **4th option** in the **Gradle toolbar**.

[image]

Comment: I used to find this option somewhere else. I guess this is new on Android Studio 4.1.3.

Answer (score 4):

To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel..

Head over [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#3.6-gradle-offline-ui) for more.

Comment: Great answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

Gradle Offline Mode is when Gradle uses the already downloaded dependencies and Gradle Wrapper that are cached on your system.

View Offline Inspection Results is tied to Inspections, nothing to do with Gradle. It is used when you want to run Inspections offline, which I don't think ever matters, since I've never used that setting

Comment: i cant find the settings to disable the gradle offline mode in latest Android Studio. Can you pleaese point it out and suggest

Comment: Which version? 4.1?

Answer (score 1):

Run dependencies.

[image]

---

Now wait for the gradle project sync.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If we enable Offline Mode, Gradle won't fetch dependencies it will try to fetch from Cache. In Latest Android Studio the option moved to Gradle in dashboard itself.