# Could not GET <some libraries names> Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Tags: android, gradle, offline

I got this error while running my project. there  have lots of research about this but didn't get a soltution. Please help me to find out the solution.

Thanks in advance. [image]

Could not GET 'https://maven.cashfree.com/release/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "disable offline mode" and "disable gradle offline" mode and this Setting in Android Studio 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635762/what-is-disable-offline-mode-and-disable-gradle-offline-mode-and-this-settin)

Comment: no , this is not online offline scenario, this is different.