# Can we ever disable the gradle offline mode permanently?

Tags: android, gradle, offline-mode

Got following error while syncing the `Gradle`

[image]

There is no use even though I tapped on **- Disable offline mode and rerun the build**

Here you can see that Offline mode is disabled

[image]

I have gone through these SO questions, But there is no use. Some solutions are outdated and some are not working

[How to disable gradle 'offline mode' in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio)

[What is "disable offline mode" and "disable gradle offline" mode and this Setting in Android Studio 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635762/what-is-disable-offline-mode-and-disable-gradle-offline-mode-and-this-settin)

Can someone help me to get rid of this issue completely? Thank you.