# keep getting an error when I open android studio

Tags: android-studio

I recently installed Android Studio and when ever I start a new Project no matter what I keep getting this error :

```
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.0-beta03/gradle-4.2.0-beta03.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project.
```

and offline mode doesn't work either . I really ran out of ideas . if anyone can help me please do. thanks.
this is my build gradle :

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

and this is build.gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta03"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and when I'm clicking on Offline mode this error appears :

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta03.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta03 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta03 available for offline mode.
Possible solution:
 - Disable offline mode and rerun the build
```

Comment: can you please add your project's `build.gradle` here? You can find it inside your main project directory.

Comment: its added to the buttom of the main text.

Comment: Have you enabled `offline mode`? If yes, please try after disabling it.

Comment: an error appears when I'm trying offline mode . you can see it now in the buttom of the main text.

Comment: Please try `Invalidate Caches and Restart`. Keep offline mode disabled and wait for gradle files to sync after restart

Answer (score 0):

The always working and best solution is to delete the full application with the sdk's if you have any projects take a backup of them and reinstall android studio. That's the most easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable gradle offline mode. You can find how to here: [How to disable gradle 'offline mode' in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio). Then wait for gradle files to sync after restart.

Answer (score 0):

Jcenter is no longer available.

You must replace all `jcenter()`s in you `build.gradle` with `mavenCentral()`.
Also check your Internet connection(VPN) and proxies because it seems you have problems with your connection.