# How can I fix this error in my Lottie XML code in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, lottie

I have problem with my lottie XML, is null this my code:

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/animationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/animation"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    app:lottie_loop="true"/>
```

This is my gradle implementation of Lottie:

```
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0"
```

This is the error (image SS code)
[image: this image]

Comment: check you are offline mode or not.

Comment: where i must check?

Comment: could you elaborate more on the issue? is there any error logs or screenshots that you could share with us?

Comment: take a look up, i was edited. add an image of screenshoot

Comment: this Screenshoot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmRWJ.png

Comment: @Alammerdeka https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya iam in online mode

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It works in the below changes:

Change version `"com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0"` to `"com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.7.0"`

also in build.gradle :

change `jcenter()` to `mavenCentral()`

Still you getting same problem goto  **File > Invalidate Caches/Restart**