# I am getting message this error below build failed

Tags: android

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> Could not download aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.3-6040484): No cached version available for offline mode

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 258ms
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date

Comment: Try enabling online mode. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Try Build -> Clean Project.
Than File -> Invalidate caches/Restart.
Than open the project and sync it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. fixed by

1. Deleting the caches folder inside bin of the .gradle folder which android studio uses found in **File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Gradle** User Home
2. Deleting **.gradle** folder in **project**.
3. Deleting the **Build** folder in project.
4. **Invalidate cache/ and restart**
5. **Rebuild** project and done! it works

Ps1: Steps 2 and 3 can be done in projects tab, top left side of android studio.

Ps2: DON'T WORRY ABOUT DELETING THOSE FOLDERS, gradle will download them for you in the next build, provided you have network connection and Offline mode in gradle tab (top right side) is off.