# Hello I try To run my app but its show me this error And I'm Stuck now?

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9suoM.png)

Hello I try To run my app but its show me this error And I'm Stuck now?? its always show error no cache available ?? I'm trying but don't knows what's happening any one help me please

my build.gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "https://cardinalcommerce.bintray.com/android"
            credentials {
                username 'braintree-team-sdk@cardinalcommerce'
                password '220cc9476025679c4e5c843666c27d97cfb0f951'
            }
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSYQq.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable gradle 'offline mode' in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio)

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project or invalidating cache?

Comment: please, print build errors as text not pics . It's way more readable . help us to help you

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File` -> `Settings`

[image]

Select `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Compiler`

Remove changes in `Command-line Options` as in the image below

[image]