# Unable to find method ''java.io.File > org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.getDestinationDir()

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**I have problem with updating Kotlin version in existing project.**

Current Gradle:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1
```

Current Kotlin:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30
```

When I'm changing Kotlin version to

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20
```

I'm getting error:

```
> Unable to find method ''java.io.File
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.getDestinationDir()''
> 'java.io.File
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.getDestinationDir()'
> 
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after
> a network connection timeout.)
> 
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network) The state
> of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle
> daemons may solve this problem.
> 
> Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart) Your project may be
> using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other
> plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
> project.
> 
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the
> IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

I was trying to:

- re-sync gradle
- re-download dependencies
- clear cache

> **Update 1.**

Updated all dependencies but still can't change Kotlin version.

**How I can solve this problem ?**

Comment: I have KT `1.7.20` but with gradle `7.3.1` can you try that?

Comment: @cutiko Changed gradle to 7.3.1 but when trying update kotlin to 1.7.20 still the same.

Comment: can it be you have offline mode enabled? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. I will write what helped me and it maybe would be helpful for someone in the future.

In this case there was problem with **kotlin** compatibility version in **gradle** libraries.

> Run build with --stacktrace

```
./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
```

and there was error not visible without `--stacktrace.`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/tasks/KotlinCompile.getDestinationDir()Ljava/io/File; (loaded from file:/C:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/jars-9/d2eb7478e0f9b31ee9b2ffc619a8e9b4/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1
.7.20-gradle71.jar by VisitableURLClassLoader(ClassLoaderScopeIdentifier.Id{coreAndPlugins:settings[:]:buildSrc[:]:root-project[:](export)})) called from class de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins.junit5.providers.KotlinDirectoryProvider 
(loaded from file:/C:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/jars-9/4ae406a23e7d8b323fd6eec4907799d4/android-junit5-1.7.0.0.jar by VisitableURLClassLoader(ClassLoaderScopeIdentifier.Id{coreAndPlugins:settings[:]:buildSrc[:]:root-project[:](export)})).
```

> After updating this library I was able to bump kotlin version.