# Sdk version issue in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

Got to work on a codebase and had an issue with one of the packages in which I had to change the SDK version from 33 to 34, once done i ran into an issue reference image below, please how do I go about solving the issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you try disabling offline mode  in Gradle Android Studio

Comment: How do I go about doing so?

Comment: android studio - view - Toll window- gradle ,there you will find an icon hovered ,just disable it, there are videos available in you tube.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio [try this]